# Remove react native dependency

Tags: react-native, google-play, react-native-camera

I'm trying to remove react-native-camera from my react native project, and after attempting to remove it, the flag: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA is still showing on my build AndroidManifest.xml (app/build/intermediates)

Below are the commands I executed to clean the project:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean
rm -rf android/build
cd android & ./gradlew clean
Removed <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> from app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Right now If I go to the Google Play Store, and attempt to download my App, it will show that the app needs camera access.  I want to remove this requirement since I'm not using the phone's camera anymore.

Any ideas?
Thank you!!